# Spring cloud dependency uses resilience package which conflicts with explicit declaration. How to sort it?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud, resilience4j

Spring cloud dependency uses resilience4j package which conflicts with explicit declaration. How to sort it?

I tried a couple of things like:

1. Added exclusions
2. Directly imported the library
3. Added bom

Nothing helped out.

pom.xml has the following configuration:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    io.github.resilience4j.spring6.bulkhead.configure.threadpool.ThreadPoolBulkheadConfiguration.createBulkheadRegistry(ThreadPoolBulkheadConfiguration.java:105)

The following method did not exist:

    'io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry.of(java.util.Map, io.github.resilience4j.core.registry.RegistryEventConsumer, java.util.Map)'

The calling method's class, io.github.resilience4j.spring6.bulkhead.configure.threadpool.ThreadPoolBulkheadConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring6/2.2.0/resilience4j-spring6-2.2.0.jar!/io/github/resilience4j/spring6/bulkhead/configure/threadpool/ThreadPoolBulkheadConfiguration.class

The called method's class, io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-bulkhead/1.7.0/resilience4j-bulkhead-1.7.0.jar!/io/github/resilience4j/bulkhead/ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry.class
    jar:file:/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-bulkhead/2.2.0/resilience4j-bulkhead-2.2.0.jar!/io/github/resilience4j/bulkhead/ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry: file:/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-bulkhead/1.7.0/resilience4j-bulkhead-1.7.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes io.github.resilience4j.spring6.bulkhead.configure.threadpool.ThreadPoolBulkheadConfiguration and io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.ThreadPoolBulkheadRegistry
```